# Content-based document Vectorization technique

Tags: natural-language, text-mining

Does anyone know a content-based vectorization scheme can be used in Natural Language Processing to represent documents in vector space??

Comment: Does [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) work with this??

Answer (score 0):

Definitely doc2vec is a way. You can also calculate doc vector from word vectors (embeddings) manually - averaging them, potentially weighted average with tf-idf of words as weights.